# $window.location is not working in ipad only with angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**my angular function **

```
self.login = function () {
    loginService.login(self.user).success(function (response) {
        sessionService.set("token", response.response.token);
        $window.location.href = "/camera";
    }).error(function (response) {
        flashService.showError(response.message);
    });
}
```

my html code

```
<form name="myForm" class="row" ng-submit = loginCtrl.login() novalidate>                            
                        <label>Username or email</label>
                        <div class='form-group' ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.userName.$invalid && !myForm.userName.$pristine }">
                        <input type="text" name="userName" class="input-block-level form-control" placeholder="Your username or email" ng-model = "loginCtrl.user.email" required/> 
                        <p ng-show="myForm.userName.$invalid && !myForm.userName.$pristine" class="help-block">Please enter the username or email.</p>
                        </div>

                        <label >Password <a class="password" href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="loginCtrl.openForgetPasswordModal('md')" >forgot it?</a></label>
                        <div class='form-group' ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.password.$invalid && !myForm.password.$pristine }">
                        <input type="password" name= "password" class="input-block-level form-control margin-none" placeholder="Your password"  ng-model = "loginCtrl.user.password" required/>
                        <p ng-show="myForm.password.$invalid && !myForm.password.$pristine" class="help-block">Please fill up the password.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="separator bottom"></div> 

                            <div class="col-md-8 padding-none ">
                                <div class="uniformjs"><label class="checkbox theme-color"><input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" ng-model = "loginCtrl.remember" ng-click="loginCtrl.rememberMe()"remember-me>Remember me</label>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 pull-right padding-none">
                                <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit">Sign In</button>
                            </div> 
                    </form>
```

I want when i click on login button then it will be redirect on seprate page.but window location is not working here.

Comment: If you google `window.location.href` and `ipad` there are bunch of similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
$location.path('/camera');
```